# C++ Can't figure out output for a class that holds player information. It outputs garbage

Tags: c++

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out this program. The class has to hold 3 player's info and output their info. My output function is not outputting from my set/get functions. Also, if I output the array indexes the program crashes (that's the array indexes are commented out in the Output function).

edit: I'll just show one profile to keep the code smaller

Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PlayerProfile
{
public:      
  void output();
  void setName1(string newName1); //player's name
  void setPass1(string newPass1); //player's password
  void setExp1(int newExp1); //player's experience
  void setInv1(string newInv1[]); //player's inventory
  void setPos1(int newX1, int newY1); //player's position

  string getName1(); 
  string getPass1(); 
  int getExp1(); 
  string getInv1(); 
  int getPos1(); 

private:
  string name1;
  string pass1;
  int exp1;
  string inv1[]; 
  int x1;
  int y1;  
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PlayerProfile player;

    cout << "This program generates three player objects and displays them." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    player.output();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void PlayerProfile::setName1(string newName1)
{
     newName1 = "Nematocyst";
     name1 = newName1;
}

void PlayerProfile::setPass1(string newPass1)
{
     newPass1 = "obfuscator";
     pass1 = newPass1;

}

void PlayerProfile::setExp1(int newExp1)
{
     newExp1 = 1098;
     exp1 = newExp1;

}

void PlayerProfile::setInv1(string newInv1[])
{
     newInv1[0] = "sword";
     newInv1[1] = "shield";
     newInv1[2] = "food";
     newInv1[3] = "potion";
     inv1[0] = newInv1[0];
     inv1[1] = newInv1[1];
     inv1[2] = newInv1[2];
     inv1[3] = newInv1[3];

}

void PlayerProfile::setPos1(int newX1, int newY1)
{
     newX1 = 55689;
     x1 = newX1;
     newY1 = 76453;
     y1 = newY1;
}

string PlayerProfile::getName1()
{
        return name1;
}

string PlayerProfile::getPass1()
{
        return pass1;
}


int PlayerProfile::getExp1()
{
    return exp1;
}

string PlayerProfile::getInv1()
{
        return inv1[0], inv1[1], inv1[2], inv1[3];
}

int PlayerProfile::getPos1()
{
    return x1, y1;
}

void PlayerProfile::output()
{
     cout << "Player Info - " << endl;
     cout << "Name:         " << name1 << endl;
     cout << "Password:     " << pass1 << endl;
     cout << "Experience:   " <<  exp1 << endl;
     cout << "Position:     " << x1 << ", " << y1 << endl;
     cout << "Inventory:    " << endl;
     /*cout << inv1[0] << endl;
     cout << inv1[1] << endl;
     cout << inv1[2] << endl;
     cout << inv1[3] << endl;   */  
}
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```
This program generates three player objects and displays them.

Player Info -
Name:
Password:
Experience:   -2
Position:     3353072, 1970319841
Inventory:
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm sorry if I sound like an idiot, this is the first time I have programmed with classes and I am very confused.

Comment: Please produce an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: `return inv3[0], inv3[1], inv3[2], inv3[3];` this can't possibly compile.

Comment: @AndrejBratoz It should compile and return `inv[3]`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen so by this logic `return 1,2,3` would return 3?

Comment: @AndrejBratoz [Jep](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33b398a9ea6a6e0c). It just abuses the comma operator.

Comment: @BaummitAugen what do you know, you're right. One learns something everyday.

Comment: @gafel Do not use arrays - in C++ they are low-level mechanism for special purposes. You should use vectors instead. So e.g. instead of `string newInv1[]` as function argument use `const std::vector<std::string>& newInv1`.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: What nonsense is this?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Arrays should not be used as the primary sequential container in C++ - vectors are designed for that. Are you advocating char[] instead of std::string too?

Comment: @WojtekSurowka unfortunately for this assignment I am forced to use arrays. And I'm not sure exactly what advocating char[] instead of std::string is.

Comment: `string[]` do not allocate any memory. Do you allocate it somewhere?

Comment: @gafel C++ inherited from C representation of strings as char arrays (i.e. char[]) but std::string available in C++ is much more convenient than this.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka this is the first time I've used string arrays. My book didn't provide any examples so I went with what I saw online which looked like any other array declaration, just with "string" instead of "int"

Comment: @gafel C++ array is a low-level mechanism which should be used only when really necessary, and for sure not for purposes like in your example. Where other languages use arrays, C++ uses vectors. If you are forced to use arrays in your first C++ programs (which would be wrong) I suggest reading some books explaining how they work in C++ because they are tricky and hard.

Comment: The program you've shown constructs an empty player and then calls output.  What would you expect the values to be set to if you don't ever add any data to that player?  Since you have no constructor the strings are empty and the numbers have undefined values.

Answer (score 0):

First:
You do not have a constructor declared or defined in your class so when you compile, the compiler provides you with a default constructor.

The line

```
 PlayerProfile player;
```

calls the default constructor provided by the compiler. This default constructor only allocates memory for your class member variables, but does not set their values.  This is why name1, pass1, exp1, x1, y1 are not outputting what you expect.

Second:
C++ will not call get or set functions for you, and I think you are misunderstanding how c++ functions work.

this

```
void PlayerProfile::setName1(string newName1)
{
     name1 = newName1;
}
```

is a function definition.  You do not need to assign newName1 inside the function.  It's value is passed to the function when a line like

```
setName1("Nematocyst");
```

is executed.

If you write a constructor, you can use it to call your set functions, and pass them the values you want to set member variables to.

If you do not want to write a constructor, you can call class functions/methods from main with:

```
player.setName1("Nematocyst");
```

Third:
Your program crashes because you are not using arrays properly.  [Here is a tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) on how to declare an array and access it's contents.

Generally, I think you are trying to run before you know how to walk.  Try not to get frustrated.  Learn how arrays work, how functions work, and then how classes work.  I hope this is not your homework assignment!